# Upload large file in Android without outofmemory error

Tags: android, upload, out-of-memory, httpurlconnection

My upload code as below:

```
String end = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary = "*****";
try {
    URL url = new URL(ActionUrl);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/*");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    DataOutputStream ds = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + end);
    ds.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;" + "name=\"folder\"" + end + end);
    ds.write(SavePath.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    ds.writeBytes(end);
    ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + end);
    ds.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;" + "name=\"Filedata\"; filename=\"");
    ds.write(FileName.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    ds.writeBytes("\"" + end);
    ds.writeBytes(end);
    FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFilepath+""+FileName);
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int length = -1;
    int pro = 0;
    while((length = fStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        ds.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }       
    ds.writeBytes(end);
    ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + end);
    fStream.close();
    ds.flush();
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    int ch;
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    while((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
        b.append((char)ch);
    }
    ds.close();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

While smaller than 16 mb, it upload success.
But while it more than 16 mb, the "OutOfMemory" error show.
How to avoid the outofmemory error?

Comment: I want to send 1024 bytes per time in the while((length = fStream.read(buffer)) != -1) loop, but I don't how to do it.

Comment: brian, please refer to my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455006/posting-a-large-file-in-android

Comment: hey @brian, can you post server side code

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Did you try using

```
con.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
```

This will help you to chunk your data into specific size, so that you need not keep your entire file in the memory.

**UPDATE:**

Try using the below method. I use this method to upload a 80 mb file without Exception.

```
public String sendFileToServer(String filename, String targetUrl) {
    String response = "error";
    Log.e("Image filename", filename);
    Log.e("url", targetUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    // DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String pathToOurFile = filename;
    String urlServer = targetUrl;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH:mm:ss");

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                pathToOurFile));

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

        String connstr = null;
        connstr = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd;
        Log.i("Connstr", connstr);

        outputStream.writeBytes(connstr);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        Log.e("Image length", bytesAvailable + "");
        try {
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                try {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    response = "outofmemoryerror";
                    return response;
                }
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "error";
            return response;
        }
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
        Log.i("Server Response Code ", "" + serverResponseCode);
        Log.i("Server Response Message", serverResponseMessage);

        if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
            response = "true";
        }

        String CDate = null;
        Date serverTime = new Date(connection.getDate());
        try {
            CDate = df.format(serverTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Date Exception", e.getMessage() + " Parse Exception");
        }
        Log.i("Server Response Time", CDate + "");

        filename = CDate
                + filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."),
                        filename.length());
        Log.i("File Name in Server : ", filename);

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        outputStream = null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Exception handling
        response = "error";
        Log.e("Send file Exception", ex.getMessage() + "");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: I try add to below of line con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);, but it upload fail for all files.

Comment: The error java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ip/web/jquery/uploader/uploadify.php showed.

Comment: * For anyone using this excellent code with App Engine: On the line building connstr, add a space before filename= (...name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=...)

Comment: @AndroSelva could you have a look at [mypost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243674/outofmemoryexception-while-trying-to-send-large-json-data-to-server-in-android?noredirect=1#comment21512267_15243674) please. I am also facing the same problem will this work for me as well. Thanks

Comment: @AndroSelva: If I want to add more parts to the multipart entity?
I just add newlines to the outputstream and add the data that I want to? lets say I want to add a json string with the name 'json', and another file.

Comment: can you please give me the server side script for this code ?

Comment: can any one please give me server side script ? plz

Comment: I believe that as a Server Code you can use this:
`
<?php
  
    $file_path = "uploads/";
     
    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
`

But please make sure that your server does not respond `NULL` to this request:
`
ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
`
because thats where your files will be uplaoded, and above code will move it from the tmp directory to the uploads/

Comment: You should really refactor this, anyways I'm giving it a try will +1 if it works fine.

Comment: To @AndroSelva can you please share a targetURL sample code for my quick reference. As I have tried but I think my targetURL is incorrect or missing something.

Comment: I have the same problem having `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` but `setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);` and my Byte[1024] does not solve my problem.

Comment: i put setChunkedStreamingMode(1024); in my code and i'm getting: 
 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad RequestContent-Length: 11Content-Type: text/plainBad Request

Comment: hey is it possible to get the php counterpart for this

Comment: @AndroSelva your code only works if I remove `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);` but after removing this I can't upload large files. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

if Server accept chunked mode, you can use

```
((HttpURLConnection) con).setChunkedStreamingMode(chunkLength)
```

otherwise you can use

```
((HttpURLConnection) con).setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
```

or

```
/* compute first your request content length
   contentLength = formBodyLength + yourFileSize
*/
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(contentLength));
((HttpURLConnection) con).setFixedLengthStreamingMode(contentLength);
```

finally... send what you want

Answer (score -5):

```
bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); //compress to format you want.
byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();  
String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
```

Best Way I tried it was successful for me!!!

Comment: link to compress method: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: the question is not about images, it's about general files

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.