# HttpURLConnection FixedLength and setChunked throwing Exception

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I made an Android Applicatiob to upload videos to my server, it's working fine but if the file bigger than 21MB it's forced close.
so i think it's a memory issue, i tried to use setFixedLengthStreamingMode method

```
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) new File(existingFileName).length());
```

but it's not working at all with the small & big files.
I passed the value to the Log to make sure it the file size in bytes and that is correct but the method not working
I tried to convert the connection to chunk mode by using this line

```
        conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(100);
```

but also this line makes the Application fails
so I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are loading entire file into memory. This link may be helpful to cater your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/9630475/830945

Comment: using `setChunkedStreamingMode` cause a NullPointerException and i this answer is using it.

Comment: probably it might be some server restriction, as I have used the method successfully. However if you to want to give setFixedLengthStreamingMode(length) one more try then you must provide complete header length not only file length i.e. length=headerSize+fileSize. There are many other unresolved posts with problem similar to it. Or If for file uploading you could check other classes like FileEntity or Sockets!!