# uploading image in base64 format.application crashes

Tags: android, image, http, upload

i am trying to upload an image over the network, but my app keeps crashing in bw
my code is

```
  package com.example.imgeup;

  import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.InputStream; 
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
  import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
  import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
  import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
  import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
  import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
  import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Environment;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
  import com.example.imgeup.Base64;

  import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
  import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
  import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  ImageView mv;
  InputStream is;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}

public void Button(View view)
{



    try{
    //String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/IWMP-Images/IMG_20130523_164101.jpg";
       String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Pictures/IWMP-Images/IMG_20130523_161730.jpg"; 
       File imgFile = new File(path);
       if(imgFile.exists())
   {
           Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());                  

           mv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
           ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
           myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
           byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
          // String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
          String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(b);
         //  String ba1="hi";
           ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new

                   ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));

                   try{

                  /* HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                   HttpPost httppost = new

                   HttpPost("http://192.168.1.4:80/up.php");
                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                   is = entity.getContent();*/


                       AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                        RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
                        rp.put("image", ba1);
                        client.post("http://192.168.1.4:80/up.php", rp, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                            public final void onSuccess(String response) {
                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                 Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }               
                        });
                   }
                   catch(Exception e){

                   Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

                   }


   }
       else                    
           Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),"no IMAGE IS PRESENT'",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
  }
```

when doin with **simple ba1="hi"**,toast prints SUCCESS but when doin it with base64, it crashes. also while converting image in base64 it takes lots of time.. any ideas on hw to reduce this.
please help thank you..

also my php is

`

```
     $base=$_REQUEST['image'];

     //echo $base;

     // base64 encoded utf-8 string

     $binary=base64_decode($base);

     // binary, utf-8 bytes

     header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

     print($binary);

     //$theFile = base64_decode($image_data);

      //$file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');

      //fwrite($file, $binary);

     //fclose($file);

     //echo '<img src=test.jpg>';

 ?>
```

i took refernce from *http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/*

my log .error

`

```
 05-23 18:51:27.719: E/dalvikvm-heap(7622): Out of memory on a 14862728-byte allocation.

    05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

    05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2082)

    05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2461)

    05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8890)

    05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

    05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)


   05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):  at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)


   05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):  at    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4632)


   05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

    05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

    05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)

    05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at com.example.imgeup.MainActivity.Button(MainActivity.java:89)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2077)

   05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):  ... 11 more

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:97)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at    java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:144)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:126)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:111)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.encode(URLEncodedUtils.java:184)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.format(URLEncodedUtils.java:163)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.<init>(UrlEncodedFormEntity.java:57)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams.getEntity(RequestParams.java:266)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.paramsToEntity(AsyncHttpClient.java:589)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.post(AsyncHttpClient.java:390)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.post(AsyncHttpClient.java:379)

  05-23 18:51:27.782: E/AndroidRuntime(7622):   ... 15 more


`
```

Comment: Where does it crash, what line? Also, what error message do you get? How large is the image, is it possible that it uses to much RAM after converting to b64? I am not sure about the exact maximum of memory you are allowed to use, but I think it is relatively small.

Comment: sir it crashes on  **client.post("http://192.168.1.4:80/up.php", rp, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()** N yes it shows out of memory.. at sum times. in log . wat to do.

Comment: You are discarding your exceptions without printing the stacktrace. -1

Comment: common dnt dwngrade it man..

Comment: For future reference: if you add information in response to a user request, you should write a comment that is addressed to the requesting user. If you had started your comment with @Wutz, I would have gotten a notification and seen your edits and comment much sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is still an issue: You could just request permission to use more memory than allowed by default in the manifest. But that will still limit your uploads to a maximum size and might not even work reliably on all devices.

Instead, I recommend you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630430/upload-large-file-in-android-with-outofmemory-error), the accepted answer shows a way to stream a file in small chunks.