# java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe) on Android

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, socketexception

I am trying to read data from server socket from client in Android.

Here are the snippets of code that I'm using:

**Client** (On Android in JAVA)

```
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    try {

        if (client.socket == null || !client.socket.isConnected())
            client.createSocket();

        // Get Input/Output stream for socket
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(client.socket.getOutputStream());
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(client.socket.getInputStream());

       // Here RS is simple JAVA class that stores information about payload and response length
        Log.d("Send", "Sending payload for pair " + RS.getc_s_pair() + " " + RS.getResponse_len());

        dataOutputStream.write(UtilsManager.serialize(RS.getPayload()));

        // Notify waiting Queue thread to start processing next packet
        if (RS.getResponse_len() > 0) {
            Log.d("Response", "Waiting for response for pair " + RS.getc_s_pair() + " of " + RS.getResponse_len() + " bytes");

            int totalRead = 0;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[RS.getResponse_len()];
            while (totalRead < RS.getResponse_len()) {
                int bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer, totalRead, RS.getResponse_len() - totalRead);

                if (bytesRead < 0) {
                    throw new IOException("Data stream ended prematurely");
                }
                totalRead += bytesRead;
            }
    }
```

**Server (Python)**

```
        # Here request_len is the expected request size
        while buffer_len < response_set.request_len:
            new_data = connection.recv( min(self.buff_size, response_set.request_len-buffer_len) )
            if not new_data:
                return False
            buffer_len += len(new_data)

        # Send required response
        for response in response_set.response_list:
            try:
                connection.sendall(str(response.payload))
            except:
                return False
```

Sometimes, I am getting error while I'm sending payload from client on line

```
       dataOutputStream.write(UtilsManager.serialize(RS.getPayload()));
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:506)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:475)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:98)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
    at com.rgolani.replay.tcp.TCPClientThread.run(TCPClientThread.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
    at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:151)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:473)
    ... 7 more
```

I know this is little bit confusing. Python code has not been written by me and there exists a python client which works without any errors. I'm getting this error only in my JAVA code.

**Working Python Client**

```
    if self.sock is None:
        self._connect_socket()

    self.sock.sendall(tcp.payload)

    buffer_len = 0
    while tcp.response_len > buffer_len:
        data = self.sock.recv( min(self.buff_size, tcp.response_len-buffer_len) )
        buffer_len += len(data)
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386141/retrofit-retrofiterror-sendto-failed-epipe-broken-pipe/54861233#54861233

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `setChunkedStreamingMode` then remove it and then see.I think I am so late but this solves my problem.You can use fixed length streaming mode.

Comment: I use `setChunkedStreamingMode` because of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630430/upload-large-file-in-android-without-outofmemory-error) . And encounter this once. It is sever's php not allow non fixed length. It should be solved in server side and not need to remove code on client.

Answer (score 1):

That error occurs when the client try to write to a connection when the backend has already closed it.
By default Android set the `Keep Alive` property to true and will reuse the old socket connections since establishing a connection is a resource consuming operation in a mobile environment (you can test it with a tool like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)). 
Try to set the `Connection` header to `close` or call `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");` in order to disable Keep Alive and thus forcing the system to create a new connection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i am missing a point with your issue, but i think it would be nicer to use this Java snippet:

```
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

ObjectOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
ObjectInputStream dataInputStream = null;
try {

    if (client.socket == null || !client.socket.isConnected())
        client.createSocket();

    // Get Input/Output stream for socket
    dataOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream (client.socket.getOutputStream());
    dataInputStream = new ObjectInputStream (client.socket.getInputStream());

    // Here RS is simple JAVA class that stores information about payload and response length
    Log.d("Send", "Sending payload for pair " + RS.getc_s_pair() + " " + RS.getResponse_len());

    // You might consider using java.io.Serializable interface with the argument object
    dataOutputStream.writeObject(UtilsManager.serialize(RS.getPayload()));

    // Notify waiting Queue thread to start processing next packet
    if (RS.getResponse_len() > 0) {
        Log.d("Response", "Waiting for response for pair " + RS.getc_s_pair() + " of " + RS.getResponse_len() + " bytes");

        // Read a java.io.Serializable object from the stream. So you have to write a java.io.Serializable object into the stream.
        Object o = dataInputStream.readObject();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

In my case: client.createSocket(); don't connect to any server - just create a socket. So later I must client.connect(_sock_sddr_here_);

Also isConnected() - dumb test because it's forever true.