# retrofit.RetrofitError: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I'm using  Retrofit 1.9.0 for my RESTclient in android, It get error like i post below:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
04-03 20:18:51.995 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:395)
04-03 20:18:51.995 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
04-03 20:18:51.995 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
04-03 20:18:51.995 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
04-03 20:18:51.995 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-03 20:18:51.996 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-03 20:18:51.996 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
04-03 20:18:51.996 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
04-03 20:18:51.996 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
04-03 20:18:51.997 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:550)
04-03 20:18:51.997 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:519)
04-03 20:18:51.998 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:511)
04-03 20:18:51.998 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
04-03 20:18:51.998 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
04-03 20:18:51.998 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
04-03 20:18:51.998 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.writeRequestHeaders(HttpEngine.java:659)
04-03 20:18:51.998 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:808)
04-03 20:18:51.998 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:293)
04-03 20:18:51.998 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:505)
04-03 20:18:51.998 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
04-03 20:18:51.999 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
04-03 20:18:51.999 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:     at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
04-03 20:18:51.999 8634-8634/up.tech.opener W/System.err:   ... 7 more
```

Can anyone know how to fixing this please?

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure that your configuration is correct

check if you have added all the required permissions to your `AndroidManifest.xml` (EPIPE happens often as a result of **missing** permissions)

Comment: "add the required permissions" he said without providing any further information

Answer (score 0):

Script might be getting stuck somewhere in the code, hence not posting the response meanwhile server would have closed the socket.

**Increasing timeout values**

```
okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Add this on your gradle**

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'   
Compile 'come.scrap.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

if not set port in retrofit helper , like this : http://172.51.65.62

retforit try to connect to : http://172.51.65.62:80

now if used any port else port number 80 , you will get this error

for fix this error change ip or address like : http://172.51.65.62:8256