# Error Posting Mp3 File To Server

Tags: android, base64, mp3

I am working on one Android project in which I need to post a mp3 file to PHP server. When mp3 file is small in size, I can post it successfully to server, but when mp3 file size is of 3-4 MB, I got error in namevalues pairs. Here with this I am posting my error and code. What can be the issue?

The following code is for onActivityResult() where I convert mp3 file to Base64 format.

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == RQS_OPEN_AUDIO_MP3) {
        Uri audioFileUri = data.getData();

        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.e("Mp3 Path==>", data.getData() + "");
        Log.e("Mp3 URI==>", audioFileUri + "");
        String path = ConstantData.getPath(this, audioFileUri);

        File file = new File(path);
        Log.e("File Length==>", file.length() + "");
        b=null;
        b= new byte[(int) file.length()];

        fileInputStream=null;
        encode=null;

        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(b);
        fileInputStream.close();        
        encode = Base64.encodeBytes(b);
        //Log.e("Mp3 Encoded==>", encode + "");     
        showImagePostingDialog("Upload?", "You want To Upload this Mp3 File?", null);
    }
}
```

This is error `Log` which I get in `doInBackground()` at NameValuePair.

```
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:132)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:124)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at libcore.net.UriCodec.appendEncoded(UriCodec.java:119)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:133)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.encode(URLEncodedUtils.java:184)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.format(URLEncodedUtils.java:163)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.<init>(UrlEncodedFormEntity.java:71)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at com.android.fikra.events.eventslast.EventLastActivity$BackGroundTaskPostMp3.doInBackground(EventLastActivity.java:1060)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at com.android.fikra.events.eventslast.EventLastActivity$BackGroundTaskPostMp3.doInBackground(EventLastActivity.java:1)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-01 10:35:15.420: E/AndroidRuntime(13428):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630430/upload-large-file-in-android-without-outofmemory-error

Comment: You have an edit mistake at `Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`.