# How can I send large File to Server from Android with AndroidAnnotation?

Tags: java, android, rest, android-annotations

I need to send a large file from Android Tablet to a server.

So now I'm using `Android Annotation` to do it, but now I get `OutOfMemory` `Exception` becuase my file is bigger than 35MB. I searched and I undesrstand that if I use `FileOutputStream` with connection I can avoid that Exception.

But how can I get output stream from my connection using `@Rest AndroidAnnotation Class`?

This is my code:

```
@Rest(converters = {FormHttpMessageConverter.class, MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class}
/*, interceptors=MyClientHttpRequestInterceptor.class*/)
public interface DbRestClient  extends RestClientErrorHandling{

    void setRootUrl(String rootUrl);

    String getRootUrl();

    void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate);

    RestTemplate getRestTemplate();

    @Post("dbSynk/postNew")
    Integer postDb(MultiValueMap file);
}
```

And into my `@EService`:

```
@RestService DbRestClient dbRestClient;

...

dbRestClient.postDb(file)
```

Have you any ideas?

Comment: Why you sending 35MB file to server ? could you please explain scenario.What kind of large file ?

Comment: @IshArt It's a .db file, I want to transfer for Backup it on server.

Comment: If this is databae file then upload it by query, one or five rows at once,,or if not then increase connection time,,

Comment: @IshArt I don't want to copy the row in another db. Is a local DB, that for backup (an user broke the tablet under a machine) I want to transfer every day on my server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630430/upload-large-file-in-android-without-outofmemory-error

Answer (score 0):

Use [`@Part`](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Rest-API#part) and `FormHttpMessageConverter`.

The commonly used `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` loads the entire file to memory, while conveting the file to JSON. Using `FormHttpMessageConverter` it will stream the file content instead of loading it to memory.