# OutputStream out of memory error while sending File to Http

Tags: java, android, android-file

Smaller size file are uploaded to server successfully but when it come to larger files the below code throws out of memory error. any solution ?? . Thanks in advance.

```
public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
                throws IOException {
            String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
            writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append(
                    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                            + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                    .append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append(
                    "Content-Type: "
                            + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                    .append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.flush();

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            inputStream.close();

            writer.append(LINE_FEED);
            writer.flush();
        }
```

Comment: Use some better HTTP client API, one that allows you to stream your body, rather than having to load the body into memory first. OkHttp [appears to be able to handle this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#post-streaming).

Comment: why are you using both an outputstream and a writer? wouldn't they interfere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use chunchedStreamingMode it will help you to chunk your data in specific size.

```
con.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
```

this link can help you
[Upload large file in Android without outofmemory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630430/upload-large-file-in-android-without-outofmemory-error)

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend you to use an HTTPClient. In addition, you should consider using [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), more specifically the `IOUtils`class to copy your `FileInputStream` to the `OutputStream` (your remote call) using

```
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```

This will avoid that you have to load the file into memory, thus avoiding `OutOfMemory` Exceptions. The file will basically be streamed from disk to the server.