# Memory out of bound while uploading a large file

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am getting a memory out of bound exception while uploading a large file to server.

Here is my StackTrace:

```
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2060 byte allocation with 1856 free bytes and 1856B until OOM
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.okio.Segment.<init>(Segment.java:34)
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.okio.SegmentPool.take(SegmentPool.java:48)
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.okio.OkBuffer.writableSegment(OkBuffer.java:511)
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.okio.OkBuffer.write(OkBuffer.java:424)
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink$1.write(RealBufferedSink.java:130)
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:98)
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.ruf.rufdrive.server.request.HttpClient.addFileBytes(HttpClient.java:296)
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.ruf.rufdrive.server.request.service.UploadIntentService.convertFileToByteArray(UploadIntentService.java:327)
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.ruf.rufdrive.server.request.service.UploadIntentService.upload(UploadIntentService.java:209)
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.ruf.rufdrive.server.request.service.UploadIntentService.uploadFile(UploadIntentService.java:407)
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.ruf.rufdrive.server.request.service.UploadIntentService.onHandleIntent(UploadIntentService.java:119)
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.ruf.rufdrive.server.request.service.UploadIntentService$1.run(UploadIntentService.java:94)
09-20 12:21:07.985  7011  7562 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is my code for the upload:

```
   InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
   bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();
   maxProgress = bytesAvailable;

   ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
   if(bufferSize == 0)
    throw  new FileNotFoundException("file not found");
   byte[] b = new byte[bufferSize];
   int bytesRead =0;
   long notificationTriggerAmount = bytesAvailable /100;
   long nextNotificationTrigger = 0;
   while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1)
   {       
        httpClient.addFileBytes(b, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();
        Log.v("Available",bytesAvailable+"");
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);       
   }
}
```

Comment: Add the exception stack trace.

Comment: have you seen this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630430/upload-large-file-in-android-without-outofmemory-error

Comment: You are not using 'bos'. Why are you creating a byte array 'b' with the size of the file? That will take you out of memory already. What is the sze of the file? What is unknown function 'addFileBytes' doing?

Comment: What is the size of the file?

Comment: @Nooruddin Lakhani, You saved my day. thanks a lot